# Rotating the left the subtrees in an AVL Tree in python

Tags: python, algorithm, avl-tree

A bit of a newbie to computing science.

I have the basics for a binary tree in Python and I was studying some of the applications in an AVL tree:

```py
class TreeBinary:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def show_aux(root):
    if not root:
        return ''
    string = str(root.data)
    if root.left or root.right:
        string += ' (' + show_aux(root.left) + ')'  # Space before '('
    else:
        string += ' ('  # Space before '('
        string += ')'
    if root.right:
        string += ' (' + show_aux(root.right) + ')'  # Space before '('
    else:
        string += ' ('  # Space before '('
        string += ')'
    return string


def show(root):
    print('(' + show_aux(root) + ')')


def rotate_left(root):
    rotated_root = root.right
    try:
        temp = rotated_root.left
    except:
        show(root)

    rotated_root.left = root
    root.right = temp
    return rotated_root


root = TreeBinary('a')
root.left = TreeBinary('b')
root.right = TreeBinary('c')
show(root)
print()
root.left = rotate_left(root.left)
show(root)
```

One of the challenges I'm trying to solve is to rotate the left side of a tree in a function that takes the root as a parameter, but I'm getting the following error:

```
root.left = rotate_left(root.left)
  File "rotated_left_binary_tree.py", line 36, in rotate_left
    rotated_root.left = root
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'
```

I tried to solve, but it only prints the root and the right root

Comment: The tree has root `a`, with left child `b` and right child `c`. You're passing `root.left` which is `b` as the "root" to the rotation method. But `b` doesn't have a right child, so the line `rotated_root = root.right` is the same as `rotated_root = None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating the subtree at `b`, but your function expects the given node to have a right child, which obviously is not the case: there is nothing to rotate at `b`.

It would have made more sense if your main code would have asked for a rotation at node `a`:

```
root = rotate_left(root)
```

On the other hand, it would be good to protect your rotate functions a bit. Let it return the root unchanged when it has no right child:

```
def rotate_left(root):
    rotated_root = root.right
    if not rotated_root:
        return root  # cannot rotate here
    try:
        temp = rotated_root.left
    except:
        show(root)

    rotated_root.left = root
    root.right = temp
    return rotated_root
```

Now your original main code would not trigger an exception, but the tree would also not change -- which is indeed the correct behaviour when you call the rotation function on a leaf node (`b`).